# How to determine if the current request is requested via redirect?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Currently, I am using urlrewrite.xml to redirect the old page to the new domain. How can I determine in the servlet request if the url was requested using the old domain?

My urlrewrite.xml rule:

```xml
<rule>
    <condition next="and" name="host" operator="equal">(.*)oldurl.com</condition>
    <from>^/(.*)$</from>
    <to last="true" type="permanent-redirect">newurl.com</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: simplest fix can be attaching a simple `query` param like `?isRedirected=true` while redirecting.. at the end of the url

Comment: @Minato, Is there another way aside from the param method?  .Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Well, I don't think so.. since its a redirection so you can't really modify the headers on user's end. you can set a cookie on user's end but sometimes user's keep the cookies off so it won't be a good solution. another solution could be dual redirection.. first link being a a simple session setter and second link could be the actual link

Comment: for example: old_url -> session_setter user gets here because he's redirected and after session_setter gets redirected to the actual link.. but its the worst solution that there is.. :P

Comment: @kryptonrock please show the relevant rule from urlrewrite.xml, it's unclear now whether you are internally rewriting or using tucket to do an external redirect

Comment: <rule>
 <condition next="and" name="host" operator="equal">(.*)oldurl.com</condition>
  <from>^/(.*)$</from>
  <to last="true" type="permanent-redirect">https://newurl.com</to>
 </rule>

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Is there any solution in tuckey's url rewrite?

Comment: Well you are using an external redirect (a permanent 301). If the referrer header is not being set, then the only option is @Minato's suggestion to use a special identifier in the url that you redirect to - it could be a query param, or a special path - something in the url.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, thanks for the answer. I have already come up with atleast a good solution for this. I redirect the page to the new domain with a custom url and the new domain has a rule that handles that custom url and redirect it with a specific session .

Comment: @kryptonrock As I said 2 way redirection might not be a good practice.. but whatever suits you right :)

Comment: @Minato. This is just a temporary redirection and I will remove it as soon as the old domain is down. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referer header in the request. It'll point to the URL of other domain, from where you are redirected to your domain.

Comment: I'm using the request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER) method. But it always return **null**

Comment: The OP is talking about internally rewriting URLs, not external redirection. (see the tags)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt. Yes you are correct. I'm redirecting the page using the rewriting rules.